# Double sign-out required in rails devise on Amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, devise, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

App running **Rails 4.2.0** with **Devise 3.4.1** on an Amazon elastic beanstalk.  When a user logs in they get the appropriate

> Signed in successfully.

message ... but the *"Signed in successfully."* repeats on every subsequent page viewed on the site.

Then when a user visits `/users/sign_out` they still get the *"Signed in successfully."* flash message and remain logged in.

But now browsing around the site acts normally with the user signed in.

It takes a second visit to `/users/sign_out` to successfully log out of the site.

This problem is isolated to the **production** environment.  So I think this has something to do with the **DNS** issues surrounding the **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**.  I had some issues in the past with trying to set *cookies* on an *elastic beanstalk* where Amazon has assigned me a name like *http://app-name.elasticbeanstalk.com/* and then DNS sets this to *http://app-name.ourdomain.com/*

So could this be a problem in the _app/controllers/application_controller.rb_ :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  ...

  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => "app-name.ourdomain.com"}
    else  
      {}
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

This was added to the application controller so that *Rails* will use the correct hostname when constructing URLs.  Without this, Rails constructs all of the URLs with *http://app-name.elasticbeanstalk.com/*

But just in case this has something to do with the *config/environments/production.rb* file I'm throwing this in:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_files = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  Fog.credentials = { :path_style => true }
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//assets.host.com"
  config.assets.prefix = "/admin"

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

end
```

Comment: can you post the sessions controller that you are using?

Comment: I don't have a custom Sessions controller -- it's simply using /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb .